# Swagger Docs multipart/form-data array format (NestJs)

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, class-validator, nestjs-swagger

I've the following dto:

```
export class CreatePersonDto {
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Person name',
    example: 'Jhon Doe',
  })
  readonly name: string;

  @ValidateIf((object, value) => value)
  @IsString({ each: true })
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Clothes ids',
    isArray: true,
    type: String,
  })
  readonly clothes: string[];
}
```

This is the cURL generated by Swagger Ui:
(Unable to parse this in NestJs to a string array)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:3000/person' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'name=Jhon Doe' \
  -F 'clothes=id1,id2'
```

(Clothes are sent as a string)

The array form in the UI looks like this:
[image: Swagger Ui with sense]

This is the expected cURL (Generated by postman, or manually):
(Nestjs automatically parse this to an array)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:3000/person' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'name=Jhon Doe' \
  -F 'clothes[0]=id1' \
  -F 'clothes[1]=id2'
```

(Clothes are correctly send as an array)

How can i solve this problem with swagger?